# MongoDB child to parent or parent to child referencing advantages

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

First of all, let me say that dozens of similar questions have already been asked over the years and I read many of them. Since I'm coming from a relational DB background, I'm having hard time to understand parent to child referencing advantages.

Here is a usual relational child to parent referencing. Many comments suggests that this is also the right way of referencing in order to prevent hitting 16mb document size limit :

`users` collection:

```
{
   _id: new ObjectId(xxx),
   name: 'User Name'
}
```

`posts` collection :

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(xxx)
  title : 'Post Title'
  userId : 'ref to user id'
}
```

On the other hand, I see many examples such as this one, parent to child referencing :

`users` collection:

```
{
   _id: new ObjectId(xxx),
   name: 'User Name',
   posts : ['id1', 'id2']
}
```

`posts` collection :

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(xxx)
  title : 'Post Title'
}
```

Personally, I can't see any advantages of second one since `posts` array will be growing and anytime a new post added, `users` collection required to get updated. Also as far as I'm concerned, first example, child to parent, works quite good with proper indexing.

All the answers and comments are suggesting the first one is the right way. My question is why parent to child method is preferred by certain projects? What are the advantages and is it something I should be considering to use in certain cases? Or is it just an older method coming from early years of MongoDB?

A simple example case would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This official blog post by MongoDB discusses one scenario where parent to child ref is useful: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern

Comment: @RamitMittal Thanks for sharing the post, but it’s related to a completely different thing called subset pattern (similar to outlier pattern) which provides a solution for slicing embedded fields into a new document when they get larger.

Comment: It's a great read for anyone trying to figure out refs in Mongo, specially storing child refs in parent doc. Although embedding does take it a step further.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question in case it helps someone. I was looking for use cases of parent to child referencing and found the answer in this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leNCfU5SYR8&t=2464s

Example case especially useful for `Many to Many` referencing :

```
Users :
{
   _id: 'userId1',
   name: 'User1',
   posts: ['postId1', 'postId7']
}
{
   _id: 'userId2',
   name: 'User2',
   posts: ['postId1', 'postId4']
}

Posts : 
{
   _id: 'postId1',
   title: 'A post title',
   owners: ['userId1', 'userId2']
}
```

This use case is referencing `many to many`. Getting a post by userId will be costly because query must lookup in `owners` field which is an array. Instead storing `posts` as an array in `Users` collection and pulling posts by Id would be much practical and faster.

Of course there might be many different use cases, but this one makes perfect sense.